# Routing after first routing filter

Tags: python, rest, routes, tornado, backend

I want to handle routes with differents entities at the same time. For example route: /user/userName/evaluation. Here we have User and Evaluation entities. 
With the following route, my app goes to UserService class, so inside that class I want to filter by route again. Until now I just have HTTP verbs inside that class (POST, GET, PUT...etc). I want to handle all routes which start by "/evaluation" and then we will see which function will handle it. Any idea?

app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/user/(.*)', UserService),
    ])

Answer (score 0):

You can create independent [router](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/routing.html#tornado.routing.RuleRouter), [add whatever sub-routes](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/routing.html#tornado.routing.RuleRouter.add_rules) you want and [search through them](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/routing.html#tornado.routing.Router.find_handler) in the UserService handler.

Comment: i can't see ur solution